# CryptoKingdom currency usage of both CKG and XMR

Tags: gaming, ckg, moneritos, currency-conversion

Most games only have one currency. Please help explain the reasons for the usage of two in game currencies.

- Is it true that CryptoKingdom supports both CKG (CryptoKingdom Gold) and Moneritos (1/1,000,000 XMR)? What is the stated reason of the games developers to support more than one currency?
- Is XMR the only currency that can be used to buy CKG
- What is the status of the idea to ask Poloniex to [trade CKG](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=753252.msg9941220#msg9941220)?
- The the CKG/XMR exchange rate fixed or it it variable? If it is variable is the a long term price tracking the CKG/XMR exchange rate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - CKG should be thought more of an asset/equity than a currency.  The town of CryptoKingdom (the game's governing body) pays dividends in-game to CKG holders based on the finances and holdings of the town.  The original stated purpose of the CKG asset sales was to bootstrap the development funding of the game.  CKG could be thought of a share in the town (game development).

2 - The in-game marketplace operates in Moneritos (0.000001 XMR), but OTC trades can happen between players for any items or assets agreed upon.  XMR is stored in a depository and in-game Moneritos are credited.  Withdrawl of XMR from the game requires destruction of the in-game Moneritos.

3 - There are no current plans to offer CKG vs Poloniex.  That being said, there is nothing stopping anyone from developing an outside tradeable asset representing in-game items equities.

4 - CKG/XMR is market based.  There is an in-game coinshop that makes the market for the 100g Gold bars (offering liquidity to sell and buy).  Buying and selling moves the price of these bars.  The historical price of CKG can be found here - 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tgIzgMza7NQsTpMO9pHke1ZVXYH7l5Sj5bHdZHItivo/edit#gid=1541996690

Comment: "The town of CryptoKingdom (the game's governing body) pays dividends in-game to CKG holders based on the finances and holdings of the town." We live in amazing times.

Answer (score 3):

Crypto Kingdom uses moneritos (millionths of a monero) as currency, and has CKG, which is not used as a currency. Though you're of course free to exchange things for CKG in game, in the same way you can exchange things for bottles of VODka.

You can buy CKG (more accurately, items made of gold) using moneritos (proxy for monero). The in game markets are denominated in moneritos, and all which is tradable has a monerito market.

CKG price is tracked by the most liquid "no frills" gold item: a 100 gram bar. It's variable, as people buy and sell it. Other gold items typically fetch a variable premium over this price.

There is no trading of CKG on Poloniex or any other exchange. The main obstacles to it happening are having someone do all that's necessary, and the exchange being interested in listing it.

You can see the historical price of CKG here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=966001.msg12020666#msg12020666